# Jedis and Redis configuration with Springboot

Tags: java, spring, redis, javabeans, jedis

After configuring the Jedis and Redis in a configuration package. I created jedisConnectionFactory and redisTemplate with the bean annotation. But application failed to run "Error: creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory'"
What do I need to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code snippets, it's difficult to figure out what exactly went wrong. So instead, I will provide the beans from a configuration file that works for me. You can compare with it to see if there is any mismatch.

```
@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    logger.debug("Setting up Redis-Lettuce connection factory");
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration());
}

@Bean
public RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(host);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(port);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(database_index);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(password));
    return redisStandaloneConfiguration;
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, ObjectDTO> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, ObjectDTO> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, ObjectDTO>();
    StringRedisSerializer stringSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper =
        mapper.activateDefaultTyping(
            new LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator(),
            ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL,
            JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
    RedisSerializer<Object> jacksonSerializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(mapper);

    redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(jacksonSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(jacksonSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
public HashOperations<String, String, ObjectDTO> hashOperations() {
    RedisTemplate<String, ObjectDTO> redisTemplate = redisTemplate();
    return redisTemplate.opsForHash();
}
```

As you can see - I am creating an instance of LettuceConectionfactory instead of JedisConnectionFactory as it fits my use-case more. For a quick reference between the two, you can use this [article](https://redis.com/blog/jedis-vs-lettuce-an-exploration/). There could be some additional configuration with jedis that you maybe missing. If the error still comes, please add your configuration file and the error stacktrace.

Comment: I followed your solution and the problem I was going through got resolved. Thank you for being precise.